# gradle artifact with dependency

Tags: maven, gradle, maven-plugin

Is this possible to add jar artifact to artifacts, which depends on another artifacts?
For example :

```
artifacts {
    archives javadoc 
    archives jar1
    archives jar2
    archives (allJars) {
        dependencies { //something like this
            jar1
            jar2
        }
    }
}
```

So I want to upload "allJars" to maven, and then, if user choose "allJars" as dependency, it will automaticly load jar1 and jar2

Comment: According to the code you supply your question refers to Gradle? Why is it tagged with `maven` and `maven-plugin` then?

Comment: becouse i want to delpoy this artifacts to maven

Comment: Can you please enhance your question then with what you acually want to do.